# What exactly does SuPHP do?

Tags: php, suphp

And is it necessary? I've read a bunch of pages on it and I can't for the life of me actually figure it out, as opposed to what apache and just plain old php already do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It starts php processes as the owner of the .php being executed.  Apache + php by default are running as a pre-defined user in the apache config.  (typically www-data, apache or httpd).  If you have files that are owned by a specific user, or want to setup distinct permissions for multiple users' sites... you can create a user for each site, and set permissions in the directory structure based on each user... rather than ensuring the apache user/group have permissions to access the files.

For example... if I have a php file owned by "bob" and it makes changes in a directory with group/owner set to bob, ... the apache probably can't write to the directory unless the permissions bit-mask gives rwx to the directory and files.   With suPHP, the php file is run under "bob"'s account rather than apache's account... and the script *can* do anything "bob" can.

Comment: Php is reading files as being writable even though CHMOD is set to 555. Could SuPHP be doing that?

Comment: Absolutely.  By default, even if you change the owner's permissions to 0, the owner still maintains full access of the files.

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't that create a security issue? Is it OK if I remove suphp from the server?

Comment: It depends on you honestly, in some instances where you want to allow php full access to the most/all files contained within the scope of the user owning the files... or are operating within some sort of jailed apache config... this might be ideal.   I personally wouldn't do such.